# とでたしか。。。出してられます: particle and tense question

Tags: particles, adverbs, particle-で, tense, passive-voice

From Haruki Murakami's preface to *Yume de Aimashō:*

> ときどき「糸井さんと村上さんとでたしか『夢で会いましょう』という対談集出してられますね」と言われることがあるけれど、それは明らかなマチガイです。

I'm guessing that it parses as *to de tashika*, right? If so, questions:

1. What's the function of *de* here?
2. What about *tashika* ? Is this its meaning as "I'm pretty sure", "I suppose"?
3. Is *dashiteraremasu* better understood as present (the book is out) or future (the book is coming)? How can I tell?

Comment: I think it should be an error of 出しておられます.

Comment: It's not so much an error as vowel deletion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The で is [definition #5 in デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/148951/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A7/):

   > 「５ 動作・作用の行われる状態を表す。『みんなで研究する』『笑顔であいさつする』」   (indicates how an action is performed. "study together with everyone" "greet with a smile").

So 「糸井さんと村上さんとで」 is literally like "with Itoi-san and Murakami-san together", and 「糸井さんと村上さんとで・・・出してられる」 is saying "Itoi-san and Murakami-san published together / collaborated / co-authored (a book)" (≂「糸井さんと村上さんと(が)一緒に出版しておられる).

2. I think the たしか here means "if I remember correctly" or "if I am not mistaken."
3. The 出してられます is more like the perfect tense, "have published". (The full form is 出しておられます. The お sometimes gets dropped in speech.) 出しておられます is an honorific form of 出しています. 「～ています / ～ている」 can be used for a completed action or an action performed sometime in the past, e.g:

> (もう)始まっています -- have (already) started
>   (もう)終わっています -- have (already) finished
>   (まだ)卒業していません -- have not graduated (yet)
>   彼は(すでに)殺されている。-- He has (already) been murdered.
>   (以前/前に/かつて)(一度)お会いしています -- have met (before) (once)

---

> How can I tell?

It would be easier if there was a word or phrase like 「もう」「すでに」「かつて」「以前」「前に」「一度」「二度」「去年」「５年前」 etc., but if not, I think the only way to tell would be to deduce from the context...